# Select nodes containing mixed content or just text with XPath

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Using XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0 I need to select direct parents of mixed content or just text. Consider the following example:

```
<table class="dont-match">
    <tr class="dont-match">
        <td class="match">Mixed <strong class="maybe-match">content</strong> in here.</td>
        <td class="match">Plain text in here.</td>
        <td class="dont-match"><img src="..." /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="dont-match">
    <div class="dont-match"><img src="..." /></div>
    <div class="match">Mixed <em class="maybe-match">content</em> in here.</div>
    <p class="match">Plain text in here.</p>
</div>
```

Obviously the classes `match`, `maybe-match` and `dont-match` are just for demonstrating purpose and are not available for matching. `maybe-match` means it was better not to match, but I could solve the problem my self, in case it is difficult to exclude these.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For "match" use**:

```
//*[text()[normalize-space()] and not(../text()[normalize-space()])]
```

**For "maybe-match" use**:

```
//*[../text()[normalize-space()]]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "//*[text()[normalize-space()] and not(../text()[normalize-space()])]"/>
==========
   <xsl:copy-of select="//*[../text()[normalize-space()]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML** (wrapped into a single top element to become well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
<table class="dont-match">
    <tr class="dont-match">
        <td class="match">Mixed <strong class="maybe-match">content</strong> in here.</td>
        <td class="match">Plain text in here.</td>
        <td class="dont-match"><img src="..." /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="dont-match">
    <div class="dont-match"><img src="..." /></div>
    <div class="match">Mixed <em class="maybe-match">content</em> in here.</div>
    <p class="match">Plain text in here.</p>
</div>
</t>
```

**each of the two XPath expressions is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<td class="match">Mixed <strong class="maybe-match">content</strong> in here.</td>
<td class="match">Plain text in here.</td>
<div class="match">Mixed <em class="maybe-match">content</em> in here.</div>
<p class="match">Plain text in here.</p>
==========
   <strong class="maybe-match">content</strong>
<em class="maybe-match">content</em>
```

**As we can see, both expressions select *exactly* the wanted elements.**

Answer (score 2):

To get the matches and maybe-matches you could use

```
 //*[count(text())>=1]
```

if your xml parser ignores whitespace only text nodes, or otherwise

```
//*[normalize-space(string(./text())) != ""]
```

And the maybe matches could be filtered out, by checking if some anchestors match, but then it becomes ugly (whitespace as text node case only):

```
//*[(normalize-space(string(./text())) != "") and count(./ancestor::*[normalize-space(string(./text())) != ""]) = 0]
```

Comment: The first one selects just everything, probably due to the handling of white-space, but the second and especially third solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I just fount that if I have something like `<td>\n<em>foo</em>bar</td>` the `<em>` matches, but not the `<td>`. Based on your suggestions I rewrote yours to `node()[count(./text()[(normalize-space() != '')]) > 0` which works fine for me.